# Windows informs me about returning an error from executable when called from batch job

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, executable, error-code

I call a Windows 7 executable from a windows cmd batch job.

The batch job at the moment is as simple as:

```
echo on
D:\programs\Process.exe %1>%2
```

The batch job is started from a python framework.

It works, the %1 is given as args to Process.exe and the output from the process is written to %2.

However, when Process.exe returns an error code (by exit(-3), which is a legal situation), a windows pops up, where I'm informed that there was an error and asks if I want to start debugging.

Can I get rid of that? In case of an error in Process.exe I would like to get that error as a result from the bach job, but most importantly, there shall be no warning window.

Thanks ;-)

Comment: that window is generated by your executable. Read it's documentation, if there is a way to avoid it. There is no way to handle it from "outside", when the programmer(s) did not implement a switch or parameter to the  .EXE

Comment: I programmed the executable, using Windows Visual Sudio. It is a very simple program without windows and just using printf...

Comment: Are you sure your application isn't crashing?  Specifically what error is it reporting?  Have you tried debugging it?  Which process does it attach the debugger to?  You could try adding `exit /b 0` to the end of your batch script.  If that clears it up, then it was your Python environment that captured non-zero return and threw the error window.

Answer (score 0):

Windows machines with some kinds of developer tools installed on them, often give you the opportunity to debug unhandled exceptions or you may be compiling your application to do this (debug mode). Also, if you launch programs from your VS environment, it will definitely give you this pop-up.  It should not happen if your application successfully returns a non-zero value.  It should only happen if your application failed to handle some kind of critical error or exception.